# Headers http are not delivered to my API

Tags: angular, http, go

I am developing an API restful in Go and my frontend in Angular (no AngularJS), but when I call my API from my Web App in Angular I do not see my headers in my backend, in special case my authorization header, because my API has authentication based in JWT.

Also I want to mention that I am using Postman and Go Request client to test my app and my headers are delivered in my API without problems.

Attached below is the CORS of my backend and the API call from my frontend.

My backend:

```
func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    log.Println("CORS Middleware")
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

My Frontend:

```
getData() {

const auth = `Bearer ${this.token}`;

const headers = new Headers({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': auth,
});

const options = new RequestOptions(headers);

console.log(headers); //Here I can see 

const products = this.http.get('localhost:8000/api/products', options )
                .subscribe((response: Response) => {
                  this.data = response.json();
                });
return products;
}
```

Thanks and sorry for my english, I think that my CORS causes problems.

Comment: this might be not related but you need to remove the comma at the end of 'Authorization': auth,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
const options = new RequestOptions(headers);
```

Do:

```
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

The [constructor for `RequestOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L84) requires a `RequestOptionsArgs`, not a `Headers`.

---

Also, it seems you are not quite understanding CORS. You don't really need to send any header from the front-end to the back end (the browser will append what you need automatically when it notices it is a CORS request). Those headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) should be sent by the server only.

For your back-end, here's an improved suggestion (should handle most cases):

```
func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    log.Println("CORS Middleware")
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400")
        // c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json") // uncomment if needed

         if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
             fmt.Println("OPTIONS")
             c.AbortWithStatus(200)
         } else {
             c.Next()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, my problem is almost solved, now that my authorization header manages to get some signs at the beginning and the end that are the following.

I attached my request from Postman and the one from the web App.

ANGULAR WEB APP
Bearer "\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTk2MTUyMTAsImlhdCI6MTQ5NzAyMzIxMCwibWFpbCI6InNlbGxlciJ9.nFV5JwB5lcN3e8CuMbNNx9Y6n1tW4oBT-5Eh8H5-YQ4\""

POSTMAN
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0OTkzODIzMjksImlhdCI6MTQ5Njc5MDMyOSwibWFpbCI6ImFkbWluIn0.v3GSiAIq6Bs5w3NPfjWT1kJF2Wv6zRrkSQY7hVDe7qQ

Comment: What do you mean? What is the current problem exactly?

Comment: When I build my header Authorization in angular i see Bearer <token> in terminal, but when I see my header in backend (go) appears this characters "\", \"" and i don't continue :(